# Struggling with null referencing issues while calling a function in Flutter

Tags: list, flutter, function, class, object

I'm currently trying to create an app with Flutter that helps a user memorize French verbs. Here's a snippet of my code:

```
class Quiz {
  List<String> questionList;
  List<String> answerList;
  Quiz(List questionList, List answerList){
    this.questionList = questionList;
    this.answerList = answerList;
  }
}
```

As you can see, I've created a Quiz class that takes in two parameters: a list of test questions, and a list of their corresponding answers.

I then define a function that actually returns a 'Quiz' object. Here it is:

```
Quiz quizGenerator (questions, answers) {
  final Set<int> indexS = Set();
  for (int i = 0; i <= 9; i++){
    indexS.add(Random().nextInt(49));
  }
  List<String> testQ;
  List<String> testA;
  List<int> indexes = indexS.toList();
  for (int i = 0; i <= 9; i++){
    var element = indexes[i];
    testQ[i] = questions[element];
    testA[i] = answers[element];
  }
  var newTest = Quiz(testQ, testA);
  return newTest;
}
```

I wanted this function to return a 'Quiz' object that consisted of ten verbs to test that were randomly picked from a larger list of fifty verbs called "questions", as well as their corresponding answers from the larger list "answers". Since I was planning to pick the test questions by generating random index numbers, and I didn't want verbs to repeat in a test, I created a set of integers called 'indexS', and populated it with ten random numbers in the range of 0-49. This set essentially contained the index numbers of the ten questions that would be asked from the larger "questions" list.

I then converted the set to a list of integers called "indexes". I also created two other lists called "testQ" and "testA" that would actually contain the ten test questions and their corresponding answers respectively. These two lists would be the 'Quiz' object's properties. From there, I used a for loop to fill 'testQ' and 'testA' with the ten test questions and their answers by using the random index numbers stored in the list 'indexes'. The end result of all this was that a 'Quiz' object was returned by 'quizGenerator'.

However, I'm getting the following error when I try to call 'quizGenerator':

```
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown while handling a gesture:
The method '[]=' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: []=(0, "to open")
```

I apologize if the answer to this problem is obvious, but I've barely just started programming, and I've scoured the internet for days without much luck. Let me know if something is unclear or if you'd need anything else to better answer my question. Thank you!

Edit:

Here are the declarations for "questions" and "answers":

```
List<String> answers = ['rentrer', 'vivre', 'rendre', 'tenir', 'oublier', 'travailler', 'manger', 'entrer', 'devenir', 'commencer', 'payer', 'tirer', 'ouvrir', 'changer', 'excuser', 'dormir', 'occuper', 'marcher', 'envoyer', 'apprendre', 'boire', 'garder', 'montrer', 'asseoir', 'porter', 'prier', 'servir', 'écrire', 'retrouver', 'gagner', 'acheter', 'rappeler', 'lire', 'monter', 'quitter', 'emmener', 'toucher', 'continuer', 'raconter', 'repondre', 'sauver', 'rencontrer', 'fermer', 'valoir', 'compter', 'bouger', 'apporter', 'décider', 'vendre', 'expliquer',];

List<String> questions = ['to bring in','to live','to return','to hold','to forget','to work','to eat','to go in','to become','to start','to pay','to pull','to open','to change','to forgive','to sleep','to occupy','to walk','to send','to learn','to drink','to look after','to show','to sit down','to carry','to pray','to serve','to write','to find', 'to win', 'to buy', 'to remind', 'to read', 'to go up', 'to leave', 'to take', 'to touch', 'to continue', 'to tell', 'to answer', 'to save', 'to meet', 'to close', 'to hold', 'to count', 'to move', 'to bring', 'to decide', 'to sell', 'to explain',];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`testQ` & `testA` are not initialized. Initialize them with an empty list.

```dart
List<String> testQ = [], testA = [];
```

Use `add` method to add data to the list.

```dart
testQ.add(questions[element]);
testA.add(answers[element]);
```

If some of random numbers are same then set would only store unique ones. Don't use the Set and directly use the List or use `i <= _variable.length` instead of `i <= 9` for the condition where variable could be some list or set.

Comment: I tried doing that, but then I get the following error -                                                
RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0

Comment: Thank you for your continued help, but Flutter's still giving me a similar error message - RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in inclusive range 0..7: 8

Comment: could you add more details? what do `questions`, `answers` represent?

Comment: Both are lists of strings with 50 elements. "questions" is a list of 50 questions, while "answers" holds the corresponding answers to those questions. I've also added their declarations in my post, if that helps.

Comment: why are you using `Set` for `indexS`? If some of random number are same then set would only store unique ones. Remove the set and directly use List.

Comment: or you could use `i <= _variable.length` instead of `i <= 9` where variable could be some list or set.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Thank you!